# Unix-mailx Maximum of addresses

Tags: unix

I need to know if there is a limit when I use mailx in a unix code, in the testing process I used a maximun of 3 mail addresses, in production environment I need to add a total of 9 addresses, the problem is that all of the 9 addresses are from clients and I can´t send a test mail to them.

this is the fragment code I use to send the mail.

```
;uuencode ATTACH FILE.xls ATTACHED FILE.xls ) | mailx -m -s "SUBJECT" 'MAIL1','MAIL2','MAIL3' ...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there is no such limit. But if you want, try in the testing process to send the mail to 'mail1','mail2','mail3','mail1','mail2','mail3','mail1','mail2','mail3' so you will send to 9 addresses :)